# Is there a way to make water rise from 1'st to 2'nd floor?

Tags: water-resources

I want to have water source on the 2'nd floor of our house so I can wash stuff there without going down to our 1'st floor... Is there a way to make water rise from 1'st to 2'nd floor?

[image]

Comment: Yes its called a pump

Comment: I trust everyone noted the date of the post. (Everyone except "community" that is ! )

Answer (score 2):

Add a water pump on the main floor of your house that pumps it to the second floor. Or, assuming your house is connected to a city plumbing and water system have an extension line added to the second floor, using the city main pressure.

Comment: If a pump is needed, then a water storage tank on the 2d floor will be needed to provide smooth water flow, at uniform pressure, on the 2nd floor.

Comment: I didn't think that smooth water flow was a requirement given that the question was for 'washing stuff'. Most pumps can supply fairly regular pressure and flow, regardless a flow regulator would take care of that.

Comment: You can get water to pump itself ... but you need an available head : see hydraulic ram

Comment: If you are using a hydraulic ram, then you have a pressure source. i.e.  city main pressure.